# In Victoria Australia can you stand out the front of somebody's house and record what is happening inside?

Tags: privacy, australia

Generally, in Victoria Australia, anything that occurs in public is open to being recorded by anyone (To my knowledge).  However, if you take a video camera or camera phone and aim it through the curtains and record that would that breach any regulations/laws?

Does it matter if you are present? does it matter what you do with it?